# How to check the checksum through commandline?

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to do something like this on commandline on my UNIX variant

```
if (shasum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 == 19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e) echo 'good to go'
```

I dont want to write a separate script text page just to check this.
 This above thing is showing syntax error.
 But there must be a slick way to get around this?

How to do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
shasum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 |
  awk '$1=="19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e"{print"good to go"}'
```

So normally you get this output from shasum

```
19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e *httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2
```

What my command does it is takes the first field `$1`, and compares it against
your string. If the strings match, then awk prints "good to go".

Note that for anything other than `sha-1`, you need to specify your algorithm.  For example, for `sha 256`, you can do:

```
shasum -a256 httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2
```

The `-a` flag specifies the algorithm.

Comment: Maybe obvious for most, but, for sha256, use `sha256sum`. Also, for those wondering, like me: [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731267) and [awk](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html).

Comment: And also `sha512sum` for the SHA-512 algorithm

Comment: Also maybe not obvious to everyone, `shashum -a256` and `sha256sum` are not different names for the same command. They are different utilities that may or may not already be on your system depending on your platform.

Answer (score 21):

```
echo "19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e  httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2" \
  | shasum -c
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply using `grep` seems to be the best approach:

```bash
> shasum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 | grep 19ed9ee56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e
```

The checksum will be highlighted when it is correct:

[image: Command execution snapshot]

And when checksum is incorrect, nothing shows.

Also:

- Check `$?` in bash scripting. `grep` exits with code 0 while something is found, and code 1 while nothing found.
- **If you are given an upper-case checksum**, use `grep -i <CHECKSUM>`.
- This approach is typically used in situations when you can ensure that checksum doesn't exist in the file name, like, `curl -o` or `wget -O` then check.

Answer (score 7):

I use the exit code of the previous/last command:

If the checksum is valid the exit code of the last executed command is `0`:

```
> echo "${PROMETHEUS_CHECKSUM} prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c
> echo $?                                                                                         
0
```

If the checksum is not correct, then the exit code is **different** than `0`:

```
> export PROMETHEUS_CHECKSUM='some garbage'
> echo "${PROMETHEUS_CHECKSUM} prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c
prometheus-2.0.0.linux-arm64.tar.gz: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
> echo $?                                                                                         
1
```

And here is the whole example with an `if` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

...

echo "${PROMETHEUS_CHECKSUM} prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo 'Prometheus checksum is not valid'
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
shasum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 | 
while read -r sum _ ; do 
  [[ $sum == 19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e ]] && echo "good" || echo "bad"
done
```

The `test` operator is enclosed in `[ .. ]` and the proper syntax is `if; then; fi` but you can use `&&` and `||` operators to simulate it.

#### Test:

```
<~/temp>$ touch httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 
<~/temp>$ shasum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 | while read -r sum _ ; do [[ $sum == 19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e ]] && echo "good" || echo "bad"; done
bad
<~/temp>$ shasum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 | while read -r sum _ ; do [[ $sum != 19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e ]] && echo "good" || echo "bad"; done
good
<~/temp>$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: @user1590011 I addded a test output for you.

Comment: Hey now its working perfectly for me. Please explain how you did this.

Comment: @user1590011 Didn't do anything! `:)`. Probably you copied the multi-line code incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah very much possible, but please help me on this what this `-r sum _ ` is doing in the above script.

Comment: Nothing special. We are reading the output in to a variable sum. The underscore is also a variable collecting the filename we don't need.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX version

```sh
sha256sum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep -xq '^19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e$'; if test $? -eq 0; then echo "good to go"; fi;
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a bash script that shields one from having to think it over all the time:

https://github.com/dtonhofer/muh_linux_tomfoolery/blob/master/verify_checksum.sh

Check it:

`verify_checksum file.tgz [SHA1, SHA256, MD5 checksum]`

...or you can exchange arguments because you have again forgotten whether the file comes first or last:

`verify_checksum [SHA1, SHA256, MD5 checksum] file.tgz`

...or you can compute the various checksums of a file (lists them all):

`verify_checksum file.tgz`

...or you can compare two files:

`verify_checkusm file1.tgz file2.tgz`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
myhash=$(sha256sum httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 | cut -d' ' -f1)
if [ $myhash = "19asdasdasd56462e44d61a093ea57e964cf0af05c0e" ] ; then echo "foobar" ; fi
```

Explanation: `sha256sum` yields both the checksum and the filename, separated by whitespace. We can `cut` it to only yield the checksum.

Comment: Dude I am getting syntax error near unexpected token `then`

Comment: @user1590011 Are you sure you execute this in `bash`? For me it works using `bash 4.2.45(1)`

Comment: Yeah pasted this whole thing in one line even then getting the error
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then``

Comment: What version of bash are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.48

Answer (score 1):

Use shasum to get the hash, then write `test <copy-1> = <copy-2> && echo a || echo b`, you'll see `a` if the hash are the same, else `b`.

If you're lazy, you can drop the `|| echo b` part, you'll see `a` if the hash are the same, else nothing. And if you're even more lazy you can even not write echo and rely on the presence or absence of `command not found` message.

Answer (score 1):

`shasum <file_to_check> | diff <checksum_file> -`

If you get the checksum in a file this might be a little easier
On the left of the pipe, the file's checksum is calculated and pipe to `diff` to compare it with the checksum (provided by the file author). `-` replaces `stdin` when pipe `|` is used

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to do this, and this is what I did:

```
s=`shasum myfile.dat`
a=( $s )
chk=${a[0]}
echo "The checksum is [$chk]"
```

Somehow seemed simpler and cleaner to me...

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s -k https://downloads.apache.org/httpd/httpd-2.4.7.bz2.sha512 | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo {} httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2' | sha512sum  --check
```

or

```
curl -s -k -O https://downloads.apache.org/httpd/httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2.sha512
```

```
sha512sum -c httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2.sha512
```