# using awk in Bash script

Tags: bash

I am learning Bash scripts.
my `data.txt` contains:

```
A Orange
B Apple
```

I have tried

```
echo "enter"
read fruit
awk -F'[: ]' '$2 == "Apple"' data.txt
a=`awk -F'[: ]' '\$2 == "$fruit"' data.txt` # returns null
echo "$a"
```

Why isn't my awk command is not working when I am using my variable 'a' with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you're trying to use a *single-quoted* string as if it were a *double-quoted* one.

What you *meant* to do when you used:

```
'\$2 == "$fruit"' # DOES NOT WORK - nothing is escaped or expanded
```

was:

```
"\$2 == \"$fruit\""  # keep literal $2, expand $fruit
```

Anything inside a single-quoted shell string is taken *literally*, so variable references aren't expanded, and nothing needs escaping - nor indeed *can* be escaped (the `\` would become a literal part of the string too).

That said, it's better to keep the worlds of the shell and the Awk script separate, so as to prevent confusion, which means:

- Use a *single-quoted* string as the Awk script.
- Pass any shell-variable values to the script via Awk's `-v` option to create *Awk* variables.

If we put it all together:

```
a=$(awk -F'[: ]' -v fruit="$fruit" '$2 == fruit' data.txt)
```

Note that I've used modern command-substitution syntax `$(...)`, which is [preferable to legacy syntax `` `...` ``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).